# Adding widgets to Google Maps Fragment Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-widget

I set up a default Google maps project.

In the `Main Activity`, the layout that is being referenced is `activity_maps.xml`

This layout contains a fragment, called `map` which is referenced in `MainActivity` as well.

I want to add widgets to this layout, inside the fragment I presume, probably a drop-down menu for selecting areas on the map.

How do I do this?

When I try to render `activity_maps` I get a blank screen, because previously I referenced the fragment to `activity_maps` and caused a StackOverflow... whoops!

So, after that problem us fixed (I tried refreshing), I still don't think I can simply add widgets, can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd separate these widgets from the map widget (i.e. different Fragments) but lay them in my `activity_maps.xml` in the way to make them connected (i.e. both in same `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout`). Or if you want that in one fragment, the approach would be the same. Put whatever widget you want in separate part of your layout and overlay your map with it.

Comment: I'll try it out, do you know how to fix my StackOveflow issue, so I can try what you suggested?

Comment: Do not put more than one thing into the qustion. You should post separate question, add relevant code and stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

I used Android Studio 2.3. To add widgets to the layout file from a default Google maps project may require converting the layout to a constraint layout.  Doing that however causes the

NOTE: This is a kludge, but it worked for me.

Step 1) Default xml file with map fragment.  Would not allow adding widget unless layout was converted to constraint format.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.mycompany.MyActivity" />
```

Step 2) Convert layout to a constraint layout. Add MapView and other other widgets as you wish.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.mycompany.MyActivity" >

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    map:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    map:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="137dp"
    map:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="157dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="137dp" />
```

Step 3:  Edit the xml from step 2. Make the MapView a fragment

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.myCompany.MyActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    map:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    map:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="137dp"
    map:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="157dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="137dp" />
```